# Echo JSON object in PHP from posting through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I don't know what I did wrong, but I have this form where an admin can insert students from multiple fields. For example, the admin wants to insert five students, each student having an `idNumber`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`, `courseYear`, and `section`. I grouped all the values with same properties because I thought I could access them easily in the php file since they will be having the same indices.

Here is my ajax code where i looped the values and inserted them in an array through accessing their class' index:

```
for(var x=0; x < fieldsLength; x++) {
    id_number[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_id_number').val();
    first_name[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_firstname').val();
    mid_name[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_midname').val();
    last_name[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_lastname').val();
    course_year[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_courseyear').val();
    section[x] = $('#addStudMainTable tbody tr:eq(' + x + ') .add_stud_section').val();
    }
```

This where I made those arrays as an object and the ajax:

```
var data = {
    idNumber: id_number,
    firstName: first_name,
    middleName: mid_name,
    lastName: last_name,
    courseYear: course_year,
    section: section
};

var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "manage_add_student.php",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {dataJson: dataJson},
    success: function(result) {
    $("#showResultVarDump").html(result);
    },
});
```

Open submitting the form, I get the posted object and in the php file I `json_decode`-ed it and I get all them to be displayed using `var_dump` but I cannot access them by their property and index and I get a lot of error like:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...
Trying to get property of non-object in...
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...
```

What I really wanted to do is access them through their property and index so I could insert them in the database but I don't know how.

Can someone please help me I really don't know what I'm doing now and what I should do.

- No hates please but just helps as I can really be very noob at this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code snippets. You should be able to access your data on server side this way:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['dataJson']);
for ($i=0; $i<count($data->idNumber); ++$i) {
    // do something with the following info
    $data->idNumber[$i];
    $data->firstName[$i];
    $data->middleName[$i];
    $data->lastName[$i];
    $data->courseYear[$i];
    $data->section[$i];
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me. I thought I did something wrong in the ajax part. Thank you.